# Unexpected Token error while passing some parameters to onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i know this question is so common but I don't know why I can't seem to fix this. most solutions were just fixing some misspelled words , misused symbols etc. pls help me. I kept having unexpected token }.

this is my code

```
<a href='#' id='editTmModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editTMModal' onclick='showDialog(\'"+data+"\')'>"+data+"</a>

function showDialog(data,e){
    var name=data;
    alert(name);
}
```

pls. help me :(.

this code works on integer but not on String.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the function? What is data? Data is a String simply?

Comment: yeah, just any string. When i tried passing integer values , it works but passing string values makes the error "unexpected token }"

Comment: I just need to pass a String to process some database ajax selection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this link-element is dynamically inserted into your website. Hope this helps:

```js
var data = "23";
var linkElement = "<a href='#' id='editTmModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editTMModal' onclick='showDialog("+data+",event)'>"+data+"</a>";
document.body.innerHTML = linkElement;

function showDialog(data,e){
    var name=data;
    alert(name);
    alert(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to add event listeners in the JS, and use `dataset`.

I'm assuming that you're inserting the HTML into the document with JavaScript somehow, so my example reflects this.

```js
const name = 'Bob';
const html = `<a href="#" id="editTmModal" data-name="${name}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTMModal">Test</a>`;
document.body.innerHTML = html;

function showDialog(){
  let name = this.dataset.name;
  console.log(name);
}

const edit = document.querySelector('#editTmModal');
edit.addEventListener('click', showDialog, false);
```